# Phpmyadmin Export Dbase getting error on PHP7 Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin

I am unable to export dbase from PhpMyadmin, on PHP7 and Nginx server.

The `/var/log/nginx/error.log` says

> 18 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot
>   'break' 2 levels in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/export.php on line 864

I have already tried `sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring` and  `sudo service nginx restart` but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem after upgrading to PHP 7.

**Upgrading PhpMyAdmin to the last version fixed the issue.**

Comment: I faced the same problem, but I can't upgrade Ubuntu. Here is a link to update phpMyAdmin in command line : https://www.lucidar.me/en/web-dev/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-linux/. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 8):

Go to /usr/share/phpmyadmin/export.php .Replace "break 2;" with "break;". Then restart apache.Problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

I just got this issue. Just open your export.php file and replace ***break 2*** by ***break***. That solved my problem.

Comment: to all the line of break:2?

Comment: Nope, I just deleted the one at line 864 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I replace break 2 by break.PhpMyAdmin then works well.I am using Nginx.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).